# Android SDK Path is Missing on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ide

When I am trying to set Android SDK Manager path location in eclipse, it is surrounded with some error massage. Here is a snapshot of it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for quite some time now. You should be using Android Studio especially if you are just starting.

Comment: First of all thanks for your quick response.I am not interested to use android studio at all.is there any way to solve this problem?? @greg-449

Comment: What makes you "not interested" in using Android Studio? Android has not supported the Eclipse ADT Plugin [since the beginning of the year](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html), and according to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#notes), you should migrate ASAP. The lack of support will show over time as you start running into more and more roadblocks.

Comment: it takes too much time in every step.such as installing or to configure all components.and it slow down my desktop also @Bryan